# Full screen Ace editor

Tags: javascript, editor, fullscreen, ace-editor

I'm trying to make my ace editor go full screen mode, 
just like youtube has the possibility to make it's videos full screen.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to resize `editor.container` to cover the whole page and call `editor.resize()`.
something like [this](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-demos/blob/master/scrolling-editor.html)

Answer (score 2):

To enter real fullscreen mode like youtube use `editor.container.webkitRequestFullscreen()` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode
Unfortunately in fullscreen mode browser captures esc key, so this won't be usable with multiple selections.